# Looking for a complete list of cities by state, with area code

Tags: data, united-states, zip-codes, telecom

Our company is working on moving our sales assignments from area codes to ZIP codes, and we need some kind of dataset to help move existing assignments to the new system.  Does anyone here know where we could find a complete list of cities (preferably ZIP) by state, along with the associated area code?

Comment: If this may be open data, then the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange would be the place to ask.

Comment: See also https://www.geo-tel.com/area-code-boundaries/

Comment: https://www.nationalnanpa.com/number_resource_info/area_code_maps.html may or may not be helpful. NANPA is the agency that assigns area codes, so they should be canonical. If you really need cities (not just shapes), merge the info with any city database like geonames.org or the CENSUS TIGER city lists (census.gov)

Answer (score 0):

[USA ZIP Code Areas](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8d2012a2016e484dafaac0451f9aea24) might be what you are looking for:

> This group layer presents five-digit ZIP Code areas used by the U.S.
>   Postal Service to deliver mail more effectively.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  From what I've looked up, .lpk files can supposedly be extracted as a .zip file, but I can't seem to extract it on my machine.

Even then, this file doesn't seem to contain Area Codes though, does it?

Comment: Chrischunli - see if this helps you http://www.extension.org/pages/63073/sharing-gis-data:-using-an-esri-layer-package-lpk#.VCt76_ldWSo